# What is the current research status in simulating many-particle systems from first principles?

Tags: simulation

There is a huge gap between basic physical laws and predicting many particle systems from first principles. It will be so amazing if we can predict most properties of many particle systems (from mass of an atomic nuleus to density/conductivy/bandgap of a material to properties of any small or big molecule) from first principles with high precision at low cost.

From Google's desclared "quantum supremacy" news I hear that they can be applied to computational physics too. But from "Quantum simulator" in Wikipedia, I feel that this still only applies to a very narrow types of problems , and we still can never close the gap to amazingness.

What is the current research advance and is there a hope to close the gap?

Note: The question is more a physics question, but physics site doesn't accept this type of question so I moved it here.

Comment: Welcome to QCSE!  My answer to this question would be very similar to my answer [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8510/8623).  There is more than hope, but quite a bit of uncertainty about timelines.  You may also be interested to see what Google's CEO has to say about it in this recent [interview](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/614608/google-ceo-quantum-supremacy-interview-with-sundar-pichai/).

Comment: @ChainedSymmetry But that is only a small molecule. Can a 10um*10um*10um condensed atom system (which can cover a piece of solid circuit or a cell) be simulated from first principle in the future? - Can the quantum computer be ever scaled to support that?

Comment: The site that would be most appropriate for this question is https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/. Same goes for your recent question about AlphaFold.

Comment: @user1271772 Good to know that. Indeed this question is originally posted on physics site when I didn't know the existance of this site. Anyway IMO such questions are equally half physics and half AI.

Comment: @jw_ Try both of these questions on MMSE. For example, compare the response you got to the AlphaFold question to the responses here https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3874/5 or here https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3849/5

Comment: @user1271772 Thats a good point.

Comment: @user1271772 I suddenly noticed this is QMC site, not AI site...you comment made me think this is AI site...

Comment: Fresh off the press: https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.09324. They "simulate the non-integrable (chaotic) dynamics of the self-dual kicked Ising model starting from an entangled state of 32 spins using at most 9 trapped ion qubits"